# Meaning or source code for callback() in node.js chat app

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, node.js

I'm trying to go through the source code for the node chat demo [seen here](https://github.com/ry/node_chat).  In the server.js file and fu.js file there is a function referenced as callback() seen here:

```
function loadResponseData(callback) { 
if (body && headers && !DEBUG) { //if they already have value
  callback();
  return;
}...
```

but as far as I can tell this function is never defined and I cannot find it as a module function of node.js, a function of jquery or a standard function for javascript.

I think I understand how callback functions work but I'm not familiar with this call and it is used frequently enough in this app that I would like a firm understanding of what it is and where it comes from.

So my question is three fold:
1) where is the function based: (javascirpt, jquery, node.js, particular to this app)
2) where can I find the source code for this function?
3) how is this function interacting with the functions it is called in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the argument of the `loadResponseData` function. If you call `loadResponseData` like this:

```
loadResponseData(function () {
      res.writeHead(200, headers);
      res.end(req.method === "HEAD" ? "" : body);
    });
```

then `callback()` in `loadResponseData` will execute

```
res.writeHead(200, headers);
res.end(req.method === "HEAD" ? "" : body);
```

**EDIT** to clarify the question in comments:

You could say it's a feature of JavaScript. The important thing here is that JavaScript is a functional language: it has functions as a data type in their own right. Thus, you can save them in variables (and indeed, that's all every function name in JS is - a variable with a function as its content), and pass them along in an argument list (as is demonstrated here). There is nothing magical about the name `callback` - it could have as well been `fn` or `whoopsie7`. To demonstrate:

```
var doubleAndOne = function(a) {
  return a * 2 + 1;
}
function doItTwice(k, whoopsie7) {
  whoopsie7(whoopsie7(k));
};
doItTwice(5, doubleAndOne); // result is 23
```

`function(...) {...}` is called an anonymous function: it is pure function value, taking some arguments and doing something with them, but it is not assigned to any name. To make a function with a name, you can assign this to a variable, or pass it as a parameter, just like you could with any other value. For example, there is very little difference between:

```
var five = function() { return 5; };
var doubleFuncValue = function(fn) { return fn() * 2; };
doubleFuncValue(five); // result 10
```

and

```
var five = 5;
var doubleNumValue = function(n) { return n * 2; };
doubleNumValue(five); // result 10
```

Comment: So am I understanding it correctly to think of it as a feature of javascript. A function, loadResponseData, is defined twice, once with callback as an argument for the function, and the command callback() will call the other definition of the function?  Are there any good tutorials of this implementation? simple examples of using this method?

Comment: No, `loadResponseData` only has one definition, it accepts a function as a parameter and calls it `callback`, then will invoke this function from its body. See my maybe not so great example in the edit above.